# pyodbc + how to update records based on user input?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-update, pyodbc

I have code where I want to update certain entries in a database based on the user input where the table includes 3 columns. If user doesn't enter any value the  input filed is empty and the value still the same the value is update based on the Record ID.

I have a tow  **user input field ** where user can enter a new values in order to update the record.

The field that is not empty I want to update the old value by the entered value.

If the field is empty i want to keep the old value with now update.

below chunk of code:

## code:

import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

```
vals_update = []
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[1:]):
       val_update = st.text_input('Update {} from {} to:'.format(col, df_result_search[col].values[s]))
       expander_updates_fields.markdown(val_update, unsafe_allow_html=True)
       vals_update.append(val_update)
       if st.button("update"):
                for n,column in enumerate(df.columns):                                            
                      if len(vals_update[n])>0:
                            query = """UPDATE testDB.dbo.t1 SET first = ? , last = ?  WHERE ID = ? """
                            param0=  vals_update[0]
                            param1=  vals_update[1]
                            param2 = int(df_result_search[column].values[s])
                           cursor.execute(query,param0,param1,param2)
                            con.commit()
```

I used the below query :

```
query = """UPDATE testDB.dbo.t1 SET first = ? OR first is null, last = ? OR last is null  WHERE ID = ? """
```

But the system crash and display this syntax error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'. (156)
> (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Your `SET` doesn't make sense. What do you mean you want to set the value of `first` to your parameter or `IS NULL`? `IS NULL` isn't a scalar value. The error is telling you the problem here. Have a look at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-a-simple-update-statement) in the documentation and you'll see yours look nothing like the syntax.

Comment: AS i  said in my question what i want is to check if the input field is not empty so the the value is updated else the value still as it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update the columns that have a `NULL` value, then you could use `ISNULL` to return the columns value, if it is non-`NULL` and otherwise the parameter:

```py
query = "UPDATE dbo.t1 SET first = ISNULL(first,?), last = ISNULL(last,?) WHERE ID = ?;"
cursor.execute(query,first,last,id)
```

I also remove the database name from the query. Define the database in your connection string, not the query string itself.

If you want to `UPDATE` only the columns that have non-`NULL` values, and leave the `NULL` values in situ (seems odd), you can use a `CASE` expression:

```py
query = "UPDATE dbo.t1 SET first = CASE WHEN first IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ? END, CASE WHEN last IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ? END WHERE ID = ?;"
cursor.execute(query,first,last,id)
```

If you want to `UPDATE` the column with the parameter, or retain it if the parameter is `NULL` reverse the parameters in the `ISNULL` from the first example:

```py
query = "UPDATE dbo.t1 SET first = ISNULL(?,first), last = ISNULL(?,last) WHERE ID = ?;"
cursor.execute(query,first,last,id)
```

Comment: I do Not want to update  the column that have a `NULL` value....Instead I have 2 fields where the user can enter 2 values in each field  and change the old values  of that record....But also  he can enter 1 value and just change 1 value of this record  and the other text field keep the old value

Comment: So you don't want to change the value if they have `NULL` value, and do if they don't...?

Comment: *"But also he can enter 1 value"* What about your female and non-binary users?

Comment: IF the user doesn't enter a value in the input field i want to keep the old value  .... if the user enter a value in the input filed i want to update this value based on the **column name** and **Record ID**

Comment: ... Then reverse the expressions is the `ISNULL` functions, @khaledM_dev . You really haven't made yourself clear here; especially when in your attempt you are checking if the **column** `first` is `NULL` in the `SET`.

Comment: maybe i am not explain what i want in a clear way.... i will edit my question and hope that it will be more clear thank you for your help.